# CasperJS: How to set the agent so the Google Analytics will ignore it

Tags: parsing, google-analytics, phantomjs, casperjs

I built a simpel indexer using CasperJS. I would like Google Analytics to ignore my agent, so all requests will not be part of every day statistic.

How should I set the Casper agent variable (header)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just not execute the Google JS code? Just edit your hosts file:

```
ssl.google-analytics.com 127.0.0.1
www.google-analytics.com to 127.0.0.1
```

(on the machine the indexer will be running from)

---

Failing that, executing this code on page load should stop the request:

```
_gaq = [];
```

Comment: hosting is on some remote location and I don't have access

Comment: well... I don't have access to the site... There should be a way to identify a request as a robot right?

Comment: I didn't mean on the site, I meant in casper.js/phantom.js

Comment: ow... good point!!! hum... when should I run this? Executing thenOpen(url, callback) will execute a callback when the page is already loaded right?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set your user agent to some bot like Yahoo or Bing, and Google Analytics will ignore it.